# MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail returns YES but not sending mail in iOS

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer

The following is my code to send an attachment in a mail. This works fine. I am able to send mails but I don't always receive the mails.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

// Set the subject of email
[picker setSubject:@"My data file"];

// Add email addresses

[picker setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:emailId, nil]];


// Fill out the email body text
NSString *emailBody = @"Hello, \n Please find the data from the iOS app in the attachments.\n\n Thank you.\nMy Team.";

// This is not an HTML formatted email
[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

// Create NSData object from file
NSData *exportFileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

// Attach image data to the email
[picker addAttachmentData:exportFileData mimeType:@"text/csv" fileName:  [self.CSVNameTextField text]];


// Show email view

if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Are you testing in Simulator ?

Comment: Side note - why do you create the mail compose controller and then check if mail can be sent? You should only create the controller and set it up if you can send mail.

Comment: You say this code only works sometimes. Then you say you can't send mail from the app. Which is it? Can you sometimes send mail from the app or never from the app?

Comment: I am able to send the mail all the time but I dont receive the mails. I receive mails sometimes.

Comment: I have changed the contents of my question to be more clear what is happening

Comment: @Raj Where are you sending the emails to? Are you able to successfully receive other emails with attachments at that address?

Comment: @JohnTopley Yes I am able to get the mails with attachments. I also tried sending it without attachment.. But it does not work as I mentioned.

Comment: @Raj Have you tried sending them to another email address?

Comment: @JohnTopley yes... no success

Comment: If you send the email to a given address, do you always get the email for that address or do you only get it sometimes for that email address? Check your Junk or Spam folders. There is nothing wrong with your code unless the attachment is too large. Do you ever send an attachment that is more than 5MB, 10MB, or 15MB?

Comment: @rmaddy I see that I get emails only sometimes no matter if I am attaching something to it or not. this happens regardless the attachment.

Comment: @Raj That's not what I asked. If you send 10 emails to the same user, does that user always get all 10? Or does a given user only get some of them?

Comment: @rmaddy the user will get only some of them and not all.

Answer (score 6):

After you send the Mail with your App go to the Mail-Software on your iPhone, you will most likely find the mail in the Outbox.

Cause the MFMailComposeViewController will just forward the Mail to the Mail-Software and it doesn't care what happens next to the message. So it's up to your Mail-Software how and when the Outbox will be updated.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I found that it would go through the mail box and say it had sent and then nothing would come through.

About 20-30 minutes later the first one came through and then gradually the rest I sent came through too.

I don't know why it takes so long, if I find out I will edit this answer, but definitely wait up to an hour before assuming your code is broken.

Hope this helps someone who, like me, might be trawling their code over and over

Comment: Did you ever find a more lasting solution? I am also experiencing this issue. Email gets queued, but (sometimes) not sent.

Answer (score 1):

In my case i had to manually open up the iphone mail app, then mails were sent and received immediately.

Comment: This should be a comment